# How to display search results in one table with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php

I have the code to do the search. But the search results are not in the same table. All search results appear in a different table. How do I make them appear in one table?

[screenshots :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oREcb.png)

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['word'])){
        echo "<center>Title do not match. Please insert the correct title.</center>";}
    else {
        if(isset($_POST['word'])&& !empty($_POST['word']))
    {
    require 'config.php';   
    $word = $_POST['word'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM data WHERE word LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";
    $sql = $conn->query($query); ?>
    <?php if(!$sql)
    {
     echo "<center>No Record</center>";
     }
     ?>
    <table align="center" border="0" >
    <tr>
    <td width="900">
    <?php while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        $dataID = $row['dataID'];
        ?>                               
       <?php if($sql ==true){?> 


   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <tr>
        <td width="258" align="center" class="style5">TITLE</td>
        <td width="170" align="center" class="style5">MENTION</td>
        </tr>

      <tr>
       <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"> <a href="admindisplay.php?id=<?php echo $row{'dataID'}?>"> <span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'word'};?></span> </a></td>
        <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"><span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'mention'};?></span></td>

        </tr>
        <?php }}} ?>re
```

Comment: You have a `<table>` within a `<table>`, in order to stack your results correctly under 1 table you need to use the structure: `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 1):

Where do we start?

1.) Try avoiding styling in your html. It isn't forbidden, but your global style is better of when used with CSS.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/

For exampe: Imagine this rule:

```
<td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"> <a href="admindisplay.php?id=<?php echo $row['dataID']?>"> <span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'word']; ?></span> </a></td>
```

that could also be:

```
<td>
    <a href="admindisplay.php?id=<?php echo $row['dataID']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row['word'];?>
    </a>
</td>
```

2.) Try indenting. Use an IDE (Notepad with some extra highlighting features and nice indenting. By structuring and neatly placing the brackets "[] {} and ()" you make code more readable and make it easier to DEBUG your own code.

3.) When using SQL, your input should ALWAYS be escaped. Maybe I'm wrong and you have a DB class that does this for you. Although, you should ALWAYS be aware of this: This could prevent SQL Injection and might one day safe your life (or your job).

*Escaping:* Making your query safe and let it do only thing you want it to do.
*SQL INJECTION:* Adding malicous characters and code to INPUT so your QUERY does other things than you want.

4.) Try structering what you are doing or the goal you're trying to reach.

```
<?php
Class DoSearch()
{
    protected $search_string;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!$this->verify())
            return $this->__html('<center>Title do not match. Please insert the correct title.</center>');

        $this->search()
    }

    public function verify()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['word']))
            return false;
        if(empty($_POST['word']))
            return false;

        global $conn;

        $this->search_string = $conn->escape($_POST['word']);
        return true;
    }

    public function search()
    {
        global $conn;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE word LIKE '%" . $this->search_string . "%'";
        $sql = $conn->query($query);

        if(!$sql)
            return $this->__html('<center>No Record</center>');

        $table = array();
        $i = 0;

        $tableHtml = '  
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th width="258" align="center" class="style5">TITLE</th>
            <th width="170" align="center" class="style5">MENTION</th>
        </tr>';

        while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $tableHtml .= '  
              <tr>
                 <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"> <a href="admindisplay.php?id='.$row['dataID'].'"> <span style="text-transform:uppercase">'.$row['word'].'</span> </a></td>
                 <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"><span style="text-transform:uppercase">'. $row['mention'].'</span></td>
              </tr>
            ';
        }
        $tableHtml .= '
        </table>
        ';

        return $this->__html($tableHtml);

    }

    public function __html($msg)
    {
        echo $msg;
    }

}

require_once 'config.php';
$search = new DoSearch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your table code outside of your loop, and only create a new row each time you loop.  You were creating a new table each time you loop.

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <tr>
        <td width="258" align="center" class="style5">TITLE</td>
        <td width="170" align="center" class="style5">MENTION</td>
        </tr>
 <?php while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        $dataID = $row['dataID'];
        ?>                               
       <?php if($sql ==true){?> 



      <tr>
       <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"> <a href="admindisplay.php?id=<?php echo $row{'dataID'}?>"> <span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'word'};?></span> </a></td>
        <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"><span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'mention'};?></span></td>

        </tr>
        <?php }}} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a table each time a loop run. Make it simple.

**Updated Code**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(empty($_POST['word'])) {
        echo "<center>Title do not match. Please insert the correct title.</center>";}
    else 
    {
        if(isset($_POST['word']) && !empty($_POST['word']))
        {
            require 'config.php';   
            $word = $_POST['word'];
            $query="SELECT * FROM data WHERE word LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";
            $sql = $conn->query($query); ?>
            <?php if(!$sql)
            {
                echo "<center>No Record</center>";
            }
            ?>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td width="258" align="center" class="style5">TITLE</td>
                    <td width="170" align="center" class="style5">MENTION</td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                if($sql ==true) 
                {
                    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        $dataID = $row['dataID'];
                        ?> 
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center"> 
                                <a href="admindisplay.php?id=<?php echo $row{'dataID'}?>"> 
                                    <span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'word'};?></span> 
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-transform:uppercase" align="center">
                                <span style="text-transform:uppercase"><?php echo $row{'mention'};?></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <?}}
                else 
                {?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2>Results Not Found.</td>
                </tr>
                <?}?>
            </table>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result is to be issued only in a (unformated) table, simply use this function:

```
function show_in_table($arr)
{
    $count = count($arr);
    $output = "";

    if($count>0)
    {
        reset($arr);
        $num = count(current($arr));

        $output.= '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">'."\n";
        $output.="<tr>\n";

        foreach(current($arr) as $key => $value)
        {
            $output.="<th>";
            $output.=$key."&nbsp;";
            $output.="</th>\n";
        }

        $output.="</tr>\n";

        while ($curr_row = current($arr))
        {
            $output.="<tr>\n";
            $col = 1;

            while (false !== ($curr_field = current($curr_row)))
            {
                $output.="<td>";
                $output.=$curr_field."&nbsp;";
                $output.="</td>\n";
                next($curr_row);
                $col++;
            }

            while($col <= $num)
            {
                $output.="<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
                $col++;
            }

            $output.="</tr>\n";
            next($arr);
        }

        $output.="</table>\n";
    }

    return $output;
}
```